# How Dispose font from memory?

Tags: c#, privatefontcollection

I'm using the [`PrivateFontCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.text.privatefontcollection.aspx) class to add some font into memory dynamically.

```
_PrivateFontCollection.AddFontFile(string.Format("FontAddress{0}.ttf,_FontName);
```

I have a `web browser` in my win form application,for each page i use an unique font and before showing each page i load it's page font to memory.each font get `176KB` of my memory,
so i want to dispose loaded font for previews page from memory (for example release font "P1" form my font collection)
How can i do this?

Comment: you would probably need to have a different PrivateFontCollection for each page and Dispose it when you change page

Comment: How many fonts are you planning to use?

Comment: Have you tried `_privateFontCollection.Families[x].Dispose()`, where `x` is the index of the font you want to release from memory? However, I don't know how this affects the state of `_privateFontCollection`. You might have to make sure, it does not try to use the disposed font again. It might even be impossbile to re-add this font to the collection (in case the user pages backwards).

Comment: @Abbondanza:About 604 fonts.

Comment: @Abbondanza:_privateFontCollection.Families[x].Dispose() donot work

Comment: @irsog Then you either have to accept the cost of `604 * 176KB = 98MB` or do it like Paolo Falabella proposed above: use a `PrivateFontCollection` for each page.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26671026/how-to-delete-the-file-of-a-privatefontcollection-addfontfile for a possible solution